# Requesting a specific view in Django multitenant API

Tags: python, django, api, postman, multi-tenant

Created a multitenant API in Django 2.2.17 using [django-tenant-schemas==1.10.0](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and currently testing it using Postman.

I'm able to create a new organization (which is the Tenant) and GET them all

[image]

Thing is, in the GET and POST requests to the endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8000/employee/` I'm getting

> AttributeError at /employee/
>
> 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

[image]

Here's my employee/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from employee.models import Employee
from organization.models import Organization
from django.http import JsonResponse,request, HttpResponse
from django.views import View
from tenant_schemas.utils import schema_context
import json

# Create your views here.
class EmployeeView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            organizations = Organization.objects.get(domain_url=request.META['HTTP_HOST'])
            schema_name = organizations["schema_name"]
            #schema_name = organizations.schema_name
        except Organization.DoesNotExist:
            return "no organization"

        with schema_context(schema_name):
            employees = Employee.objects.all()
            data = {"results": list(employees.values("id","name"))}
            return JsonResponse(data)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            organizations = Organization.objects.get(domain_url=request.META['HTTP_HOST'])
            schema_name = organizations.schema_name
        except Organization.DoesNotExist:
            return "no organization"

        with schema_context(schema_name):
            name = json.loads(request.body)['name']
            employee = Employee(name=name)
            employee.save()
            return "Employee added successfully"
```

Here's the output in the terminal

```
Internal Server Error: /employee/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
[18/Jan/2021 19:56:01] "GET /employee/ HTTP/1.1" 500 64243
```

and here is the Traceback in Postman

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/employee/

Django Version: 2.2.17
Python Version: 3.9.0
Installed Applications:
['tenant_schemas',
 'organization',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'employee']
Installed Middleware:
['tenant_schemas.middleware.TenantMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
  96.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /employee/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Can you copy and past the full stacktrace? It references the line that throws the error that will be helpful.

Comment: @schillingt done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're returning raw strings from your views. You need to return instances of `HttpResponse` (or use `render`, etc)

For example you have the following:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        organizations = Organization.objects.get(domain_url=request.META['HTTP_HOST'])
        schema_name = organizations["schema_name"]
        #schema_name = organizations.schema_name
    except Organization.DoesNotExist:
        return "no organization"
```

It's hitting the `return "no organization"` code branch which then breaks Django's middleware expectations.

Comment: Right... I've done that before (as the imports show up) but didn't like the outcome (always getting "no organization") and then overcomplicated it for no aparent reason... Thanks!

Comment: (upvote limit reached, can only give +1 tomorrow)